# How to create firefox3 sidebar?

Tags: xul, firefox-3, sidebar

Hi I want to create sidebar in Firefox 3 but have no clue how to do this.

I find tutorial on MDC (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_a_Firefox_sidebar) but after installation extension do not work with "not compatible with Firefox 3.0.3" error.

Does anybody have any tip or link to some resource about how to make sidebar?

Answer (score 8):

Well, a Firefox extension, be it a sidebar, toolbar or whatever other type of extension is basically a mix of XUL and Javascript, all packaged nice and tidy into an installer package called an XPI.

For an excelent XUL tutorial see http://xulplanet.mozdev.org/tutorials/xultu/.
For information about building extensions and the package format see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension.

For a sidebar you basically have to override the browser's sidebar area by using an overlay. For good overlay information check out MDC and the excerpt at http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/mozilla/excerpt/FirefoxHacks_chap01/.

All you need except the links above is knowledge of XML, some Javascript and a creative mind.

To fix the problem you faced above, you have to specify the correct version of Firefox in the *install.rdf* file. For Firefox 3 set maxVersion to:

```
        <em:maxVersion>3.*</em:maxVersion>
```